# How to Get Login page when every time application run in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set Login page as the start page for my asp.net application. When the application first time running Login page came and after login success redirecting to the dashboard. But when I stop the running and again start the application automatically redirecting to Dashboard. How to prevent this and set Login page as start page when every time application run?

Comment: Don't solve this by "setting a start page". Manage the lifetime of your Session and security cookie.

Comment: How to manage that? @HenkHolterman

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your valid login credentials in a cookie and check on your other pages' that if the cookie exists then only allow to view the page else redirect to login page. Please check the below link for a complete understanding as well as tutorial on how to use cookies.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies